# You are trying to access item that no longer exists. The most probable reason is that it has been deleted by another user sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity

I have uploaded my new sitefinity from my local to my server but when I tried to login  but its just showing error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.You are trying to access item that no longer exists. The most probable reason is that it has been deleted by another user.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Telerik.Sitefinity.SitefinityExceptions.ItemNotFoundException: You are trying to access item that no longer exists. The most probable reason is that it has been deleted by another user.
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I am new to sitefinity. Everything is working fine on my local but while on server its creating the issue. I am working on sitefinity 7.0.

Comment: Having the same issue in Sitefinity 10 on shared hosting.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/deployment

Make sure you have completed all the steps.

Comment: Following those instructions made no difference

Answer (score -1):

Following the link in the answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24241856/55718)

The main step I needed to do was make App_Data be controllable by the AppPool user.  Then I had to rebuild the solution.  This is on version 13.3, so still an issue overall but well documented and showed I just didn't follow the rules given.